# The cursor is not moving from one input to the next by pressing an Enter button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I want the cursor to move from one input to the next only when the enter button is pressed. And when it reaches the last input, I want it to move it to the first input again (like a loop). The problem is with this JavaScript code. I have generated it using OpenAI Playground.

Is adding event listeners to buttons necessary in this case? If so, how to call this code in input fields?

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            var nextInput = inputs[inputs.indexOf(e.target) + 1];
            if (nextInput) {
                nextInput.focus();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

The complete html is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Inserting meaning
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
#one
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:90%;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

    inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                var nextInput = inputs[inputs.indexOf(e.target) + 1];
                if (nextInput) {
                    nextInput.focus();
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
<div align ="center">
<h1>
Meaning In Sentence
</h1>
<div>
<h3>
Sentence:
</h3>
<input type="text" id="sentence" class="form-control" style="width:80%"  placeholder="Enter the sentence">

</div>

<br>
<h3>
Difficult Word:
</h3>
<input type="text" id="word" class="form-control" style="width:80%"  placeholder="Enter the difficult word">
<br>
<h3>
Meaning:
</h3>
<input type="text" id="meaning" class="form-control" style="width:80%"  onchange="func()" placeholder="Enter the meaning">
<br>

</div>
<br>
<div class="h5" align = "center" id="modifiedsentence" onchange="func()">
<div>

<script>
    function func()
    {
        
        var s=document.getElementById("sentence").value.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
        var w=document.getElementById("word").value;
        var m=document.getElementById("meaning").value;
        s=s[0].toUpperCase()+s.slice(1);
        var f=s.replace(w,w+" ("+m+") ")+"<br>"+
        document.getElementById("modifiedsentence").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("modifiedsentence").innerHTML = f.toString();
        document.getElementById("sentence").value = " ";
        document.getElementById("word").value = " ";
        document.getElementById("meaning").value = " ";
       mvCursor();
        // console.log(f);
    }

    </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should embrace web standards and stick with tab = next field / shift-tab = previous field / enter = submit form

Comment: Did you check your browser console for errors?   `inputs.indexOf is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to bee zero's answer above:

You can check for the last input element and when return key is pressed reaches the last input element, you can focus to in zeroth index.

`const nextinputIndex = index < (inputs.length - 1) ? (index + 1) : 0;`

Test snippet:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         Inserting meaning
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         #one
         {
         margin-left:auto;
         margin-right:auto;
         width:90%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      
      <div align ="center">
         <h1>
            Meaning In Sentence
         </h1>
         <div>
            <h3>
               Sentence:
            </h3>
            <input type="text" id="sentence" class="form-control" style="width:80%"  placeholder="Enter the sentence">
         </div>
         <br>
         <h3>
            Difficult Word:
         </h3>
         <input type="text" id="word" class="form-control" style="width:80%"  placeholder="Enter the difficult word">
         <br>
         <h3>
            Meaning:
         </h3>
         <input type="text" id="meaning" class="form-control" style="width:80%"  onchange="func()" placeholder="Enter the meaning">
         <br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="h5" align = "center" id="modifiedsentence" onchange="func()">
      <div>
         
      </div>
      <script>
        function func()
        {

            var s=document.getElementById("sentence").value.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
            var w=document.getElementById("word").value;
            var m=document.getElementById("meaning").value;
            s=s[0].toUpperCase()+s.slice(1);
            var f=s.replace(w,w+" ("+m+") ")+"<br>"+
            document.getElementById("modifiedsentence").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("modifiedsentence").innerHTML = f.toString();
            document.getElementById("sentence").value = " ";
            document.getElementById("word").value = " ";
            document.getElementById("meaning").value = " ";
           // mvCursor(); REMOVING AS THIS IS NOT DEFINED
            // console.log(f);
        }
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
        inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
          input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                  const nextinputIndex = index < (inputs.length - 1) ? (index + 1) : 0;
                  var nextInput = inputs[nextinputIndex];
                  if (nextInput) {
                      nextInput.focus();
                  }
              }
          })
      });
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index param in forEach to grasp the index.

```
      inputs.forEach((input, index) => { // HERE grab the index
          input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                  var nextInput = inputs[index + 1];  // // HERE use the index
                  if (nextInput) {
                      nextInput.focus();
                  }
              }
          })
      });
```

Complete snippet to test:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         Inserting meaning
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         #one
         {
         margin-left:auto;
         margin-right:auto;
         width:90%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      
      <div align ="center">
         <h1>
            Meaning In Sentence
         </h1>
         <div>
            <h3>
               Sentence:
            </h3>
            <input type="text" id="sentence" class="form-control" style="width:80%"  placeholder="Enter the sentence">
         </div>
         <br>
         <h3>
            Difficult Word:
         </h3>
         <input type="text" id="word" class="form-control" style="width:80%"  placeholder="Enter the difficult word">
         <br>
         <h3>
            Meaning:
         </h3>
         <input type="text" id="meaning" class="form-control" style="width:80%"  onchange="func()" placeholder="Enter the meaning">
         <br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="h5" align = "center" id="modifiedsentence" onchange="func()">
      <div>
         
      </div>
      <script>
        function func()
        {

            var s=document.getElementById("sentence").value.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
            var w=document.getElementById("word").value;
            var m=document.getElementById("meaning").value;
            s=s[0].toUpperCase()+s.slice(1);
            var f=s.replace(w,w+" ("+m+") ")+"<br>"+
            document.getElementById("modifiedsentence").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("modifiedsentence").innerHTML = f.toString();
            document.getElementById("sentence").value = " ";
            document.getElementById("word").value = " ";
            document.getElementById("meaning").value = " ";
           // mvCursor(); REMOVING AS THIS IS NOT DEFINED
            // console.log(f);
        }
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
        inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
          input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                  var nextInput = inputs[index + 1];
                  if (nextInput) {
                      nextInput.focus();
                  }
              }
          })
      });
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's great! I appreciated it, but the cursor does not go from the last input to the first. Any remedy?

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to make a little loop to find the next input.

```
var nextInput = e.target.nextElementSibling;
var found = false;
while (nextInput) {
    if (nextInput.classList.contains("form-control")) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    nextInput = nextInput.nextElementSibling
}
```

Comment: `.next()` will get the next sibling, then *filter* to `input`.  None of the inputs in OPs HTML have an `input` as the next sibling and the first one doesn't have any next() sibling.   This would not work and would not work in the majority of cases.  It's rare there there would be inputs next to each other without labels etc between